# Specifying Bayesian Spatially lagged dependent (SAR) variable regression in winBUGS or Stan

Tags: r, spatial-statistics, autocorrelation

I have been looking for code example on how to specify a SAR spatially lagged dependent variable regression in winBUGS (geoBUGS) or, if possible, in Stan.

I mean, something of the format:

```
Y = beta_0 + beta_1*Y*W + ... + e
```

Where W is the weight matrix identifying neighborhood of geographical areas.

Notice that I am not looking for a CAR model, i.e. when the errors are spatially auto correlated, but specifically for a SAR lag model.

Can anyone help with some code example or any source suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you would like an AR(II) process term to account for serial autocorrelation.

Here is example WinBUGS code for running a Simultaneous Autoregressive model with an AR(II) term that could be adapted for your problem.

```
model;
{
# Defines likelihood
for(i in 1:I){ D[i, 2:(I+2)] ~ dmulti(C[i,], D[i, 1]); }

for(i in 1:(I-1)){
    lphi[i] <- log(phi[i])
    logit(phi[i]) <- beta + e[i]
    for(j in (i+1):I){
            C[i, j] <- lambda[j]*exp(sum(lphi[i:(j-1)]))
    }
    for (j in 1:i){
        C[i+1, j] <- 0
    }
}
for(i in 1:I){
    C[i, i] <- lambda[i]
    C[i, I+1] <- 1 - sum(C[i, 1:I])
}

# Defines epsilon    
e[1] ~ dnorm(mu[1], tau1)
e[2] ~ dnorm(mu[2], tau2)
mu[1] <- 0
mu[2] <- (rho[1]/(1-rho[2]))*e[1]
tau1 <- ((1+rho[2])/(1-rho[2]))*((1-rho[2])*(1-rho[2]) - rho[1]*rho[1])*tau
tau2 <- tau*(1 - rho[2]*rho[2])
for(i in 3:(I-1)){
    e[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i],tau)
    mu[i] <- rho[1]*e[i-1] + rho[2]*e[i-2]
}
sigma <- 1/sqrt(tau)

#  Prior distribution
for(i in 1:2){beta[i] ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)}
beta ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
for(i in 1:I){lambda[i] ~ dunif(0, 1)}
tau ~ dgamma(0.001, 0.001)

## Prior for rho is approx (uniform on the AR(II) stationary triangle)
rho[1] ~ dunif(l, u)
u <- abs(1 - rho[2])
l <- -u
rho[2] ~ dunif(-1, 1)    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a specification in RJAGS, which you can probably port over to winbugs or stan pretty easily. It is taken from [these lecture notes](http://www2.stat.duke.edu/~cr173/Sta444_Sp17/rmds/Lec19.Rmd) by Colin Rundel.
The [accompanying slides can be found here](http://www2.stat.duke.edu/~cr173/Sta444_Sp17/).  Note that the model is incorrect on the lecture pdf, (and is crossed out in the annotated pdf), but is different in the rmd file.

````
```{r echo=FALSE}
sar_model = "model{
  C <- (I - phi * W_tilde)
  Sigma_inv <- tau * t(C) %*% D %*% C
  mu <- beta0 + beta1*x

  y ~ dmnorm(mu, Sigma_inv)
  y_pred ~ dmnorm(mu, Sigma_inv)

  beta0 ~ dnorm(0, 1/100)
  beta1 ~ dnorm(0, 1/100)

  tau <- 1 / sigma2
  sigma2 ~ dnorm(0, 1/100) T(0,)
  phi ~ dunif(-0.99, 0.99)
}"
cat(sar_model,"\n")
```

```{r}
D_inv = diag(1/diag(D))
W_tilde = D_inv %*% W
I = diag(1, ncol=length(y), nrow=length(y))
```
````